# Is this the right way to express concession using inversion?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatical to say:

> May the emotions be controlled, it is not easy to do that.

Obviously what I want to say is:

> Even if the emotions may be controlled, it is not easy to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds awkward because the first part is not a complete thought (it's a modal verb introducing a subjunctive phrase), and needs to be joined to the second part somehow, for example, with *though* or *but*:

> Though the emotions may be controlled, it is not easy to do that.
>   The emotions may be controlled, but it is not easy to do that.

There is a subtle difference, I think, between *the emotions* and just *emotions*, and in this context omitting *the* sounds a little bit better, because you're talking about emotions in general:

> Though emotions may be controlled, it is not easy to do that.

The final *that* also sounds a bit formal, or just odd. Typically we say *do that* for emphasis, especially to express contrast between two things:

> Don't do that! Do this instead.
>   He told me to leave, but I didn't want to do that at all.

In this context *do so* may flow better, and it has the same meaning.

> Though emotions may be controlled, it is not easy to do so.

Answer (score 2):

What you may be thinking of is this:

> - Should France agree to transfer
>     control of the operation to NATO, this
>     might improve relations with Turkey.
> - Had there been more frequent security
>     checks in Fukushima Daiichi, the
>     current crisis would have been much
>     less serious, so say some foreign
>     experts.
> - I'd never
>     give them a single penny, even were I a rich man. *(old fashioned)*
> - Be that as it may, this house is too expensive.

Comment: Or maybe *Be he ever so brave, he can't win this fight* (also somewhat archaic)

Comment: Yes, I think this is what the OP meant. But this construction is only (or almost only) available to express "if", not other subordinators such as "though". It is also pretty well incompatible with "may".

Comment: @psmears: I've added a less archaic "be" example.

Comment: @ColinFine: Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

`As` can be used to express concession (usually expressed by `although`), but it requires fronting of the "emphasis" element:

`Controlled as the emotions may be...,`

Or more commonly in American English:

`As controlled as the emotions may be...,`